# finding iteration formula for points arranged in a triangle

Tags: objective-c, loops, cocos2d-iphone, iteration

I want to arrange my sprites at the following points using a for loop:

```
ccp(240.0, 160.0);
ccp(300.0, 120.0);
ccp(300.0, 200.0);
ccp(360.0, 80.0);
ccp(360.0, 160.0);
ccp(360.0, 240.0);
```

I am trying to get an iteration formula for these points using a for loop. I've been at it for a while. Below is the visual representation of points. Please help.

```
        *

    *

*       *

    *

        *
```

Comment: Do you want to generate points using for loop? If so this is a bad idea and not worth time. If you just need to iterate through array of points you need to store your points in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? (its a quick, sketch only)

Assume initial parameters:

```
initPoint (x0, y0)

initVector (vX,vY)

num of iteration c

index = c

while index

 for(j = index, currentPoint = initPoint+(c-index)*(0,2*vY); j;j--, currentPoint += initVector)
    draw currentPoint

index--
```

Basically the main idea is, that you start from the top right point, and shifts the context of the drawing with the initial vector as many times, as the iteration holds (to the bottom left corner) and draws the points. Then shifts the initial point down along the y axis and repeat minus one times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

I didn't spend but a couple of minutes thinking about it, but it makes it easier if you start from the largest row and work your way down:

**PatternTest.h**

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface PatternTest : CCLayer
@end
```

**PatternTest.m**

```
@implementation PatternTest
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        CCNode *grid = [self generateArrowPatternWithBaseRowOfNumSprites:5 spacedApart:ccp(25.0f, 25.0f)];
        [grid setPosition:ccp(50.0f,50.0f)];
        [self addChild:grid];

    }

    return self;
}

-(CCNode *) generateArrowPatternWithBaseRowOfNumSprites:(float) numSprites spacedApart:(CGPoint) space
{
    CCNode* patternNode = [CCNode node];
    CGPoint tempPos = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
    float offset = 0.0f;
    while (numSprites > 0)
    {
        for(int x=numSprites;x>0;x--)
        {
            CCSprite *patternSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
            [patternSprite setScale: 0.3f];
            [patternSprite setPosition: tempPos];
            [patternNode addChild:patternSprite];
            tempPos = ccpAdd(tempPos, ccp(0.0f,space.y));
        }

        tempPos = ccp(tempPos.x, 0.0f);
        offset = offset + (space.y / 2.0f);
        tempPos = ccpAdd(tempPos, ccp(space.x, offset));
        numSprites -= 1;
    }
    return patternNode;
}
@end
```